# Quitar resaltado ortográfico/gramatical en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Tengo comentarios en mi código pero, al estar en español y no inglés, el editor me los marca como incorrectos y subraya las palabras o recomienda correcciones, lo que hace difícil leer el código.

¿Cómo desactivo la corrección gramatical de mis comentarios?

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Basado en esta [respuesta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18743560/3695983).

Puedes descargarte un diccionario ASCII en Español (o en cualquier otro lenguaje) desde la página http://www.winedt.org/dictASCII.html y entonces añadir a Android Studio de la siguiente forma:

1. Ve a Settings -> Spelling -> Dictionaries
2. Pulsa en el botón de +
3. Selecciona la ruta a donde tengas los diccionarios (dentro tendrás ficheros de texto plano con la extensión .div que contendrán listas de palabras)
4. Reinicia Android Studio (opcional)

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta aceptada funciona, pero si ahora escribes una variable en italiano tendrás el mismo problema. La mejor solución para esto es simplemente desactivar la Inspección de Typo (o errores ortográficos en general). Para ello deberás ir a:

**Settings > Editor > Inspeccions.**

y casi hasta abajo encontraras:

**Proofreading > Typo.**

Desactivas la casilla, aplicas cambios y listo, no tendrás esas molestas inspecciones nunca más (irónicamente tengo mi AS en inglés, pero fácilmente encuentras las opciones de configuración).

Answer (score 0):

Hola te recomiendo leer este apartado de Stack Overflow 
[¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Te refieres a las opciones de android studio? es en el siguiente apartado

Settings -> Spelling -> Dictionaries

Te recomiendo que envés de quitarla instales la de español

Saludos!

---

La ironía de las cosas